# How to set up references between twig file and assets files(CSS, Js) in Silex?

Tags: php, css, twig, assets, silex

Before I start I want to say that I am new to working with this framework and some of its features I do not fully understand.

So, I have the following structure:

Desired assets folder location:

- web

  - assets

    - css

      - file.css

Current twig views location:

- src

  - App

    - views

      - file.html.twig

So the "web" and "src" are on the same level. Now how can I link the CSS for the "file.html.twig"? I also read the Silex cookbook (http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/assets.html) but I don't quite understand where do I have to write every step presented there. Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to use `{{ app.request.basepath }}/assets/css/file.css` - does this not work?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, but I get a 404 on the network console.  Do I have to install something else? Or add some new services?

Comment: You don't indicate what `{{ app.request.basepath }}/assets/css/file.css` is resolving to?

Answer (score 2):

The app.request.basepath is a link the base path of your application, e.g. the public (accessible) php file where you instanciate and run you Silex application.

Mine is an index.php in /web, so writing `{{ app.request.basepath }}/assets/css/file.css` is OK and leads to 'web/assets/css/file.css', but my guess is thaht you did not put your main index.php file in /web directory (maybe in a sub-directory). You should check that first.

I'm quite new to Silex as well so you should take my words with caution, but taking a look at it doesn't cost anything after all ;)